# How to increase offset limit to scrape the response from a website?

Tags: java, url, response, offset

I need to get all the companies from this website

```
http://compras.dados.gov.br/fornecedores/v1/fornecedores.json?offset=500
```

If I increase the value of offset beyond `500` I get a `NullPointerException`

```
"count": 435306,
"offset": 500
```

This is the value at the end of the json.

Comment: Your questions look too vague. Is the exception thrown in your code or it is returned from the request? If it is from the request then you should research the API documentation instead.

Comment: The exception is returned from the request.